# What is an Alef iteration operator?

Tags: loops, iterator, operators, iteration

In [Alef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alef_%28programming_language%29), what is the iteration operator `::` and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration operator `::` in an expression (called an *iteration expression*) allows the containing statement to be executed multiple times, based on its two operands, which provide the integral bounds for the execution. It acts as if a loop is constructed around the statement. For example, the following two functions have identical semantics:

```
void foo1() { print(1::5); }
void foo2() { print(1); print(2); print(3); print(4); }
```

The operands for `::` are evaluated before the loop, as if

```
void foo3() {
    int counter = 1;
    int end = 5;
    for (; counter < end; ++counter)
        print(counter);
}
```

Note, that it is also possible to store the counter value to some variable at each loop iteration, for example, the following two functions are semantically equivalent:

```
void bar1() {
    int i;
    printTwoNumbers(i = 1::5, i);
}
void bar2() {
    printTwoNumbers(1, 1);
    printTwoNumbers(2, 2);
    printTwoNumbers(3, 3);
    printTwoNumbers(4, 4);
}
```

This can be used for neat tricks like

```
int i;
pInt[i = 0::100] = i;
```

to initialize integers at `pInt[0]`, `pInt[1]`, `pInt[2]`, ..., `pInt[99]` to `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `99`.

See the [Alef Language Reference Manual](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/2nd_edition/papers/alef/ref) ([PDF](https://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/alef.pdf)) for reference. The manual also provides two neat examples for copying strings (i.e. `strcpy`) which uses the iteration operator.